# ASP.NET MVC how fill or change property of an attribute dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an attribute on a constant field like this:

```
[Privilege(SysCaption = "")]
public const string View_Course_IndexSelf = "View Course IndexSelf";
```

I need to fill `SysCaption` in the attribute with a value loaded from `web.config`.

How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can get a key from the web.config via the WebConfigurationManager: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourKeyHere"]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the value of an attribute at runtime, those values are hardcoded into the code.

You can, of course, use the attribute properties during execution to lookup other items of data that are dynamic.

In your case, the attribute property "SysCaption" could be set to a label or marker, that some other code ( I guess whatever the Privilege attribute is related to) will do the dynamic lookup.